# What can be done with an iframe and Chrome bubble status-bar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

**Pretext:**

I have an iframe on my website that loads the itunes app store:

https://itunes.apple.com/ca/genre/ios-education/id6017?mt=8

I want users to be able to use this website in an iframe (or something similar *object-data*) to find an app and then find the app's **ID Number**. So far, I have concluded that this can only be done by drawing the user's attention to the bubble status bar at the bottom left of the window when they hover over the link to the app. The bubble status bar gives the URL of the app which includes the app ID.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/baKs1.gif

**Questions:**

1. Is there a more intuitive way to help users get app ids?
2. Is there any way to utilize the bubble status bar using JavaScript? (i.e. an event handler / .postMessage())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a more intuitive way to help users get app ids?

Sure. Get them to click on it, and read the `<iframe>`’s `contentWindow`’s `location`. You can also ask for a right-click/copy link and parse it out of a textbox on your page they paste it into.

> Is there any way to utilize the bubble status bar using JavaScript? (i.e. an event handler / .postMessage())

No. (There was a way to *set* it once, in the form of `window.status`, but it was abused.) Plus, if you want this to work on mobile…